# PHP - update multidimensional array value where key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following array:

```
 $sections = array(
                0 => array(
                    'id' => 'betrothed_details',
                    'name' => 'About us',
                    'order' => '1',
                    'menu_name' => '',
                    'display' => '1'
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'id' => 'events',
                    'name' => 'Events',
                    'display' => '1',
                    'order' => '2',
                    'menu_name' => ''
                ),
                2 => array(
                    'id' => 'gallery',
                    'name' => 'Gallery',
                    'order' => '3',
                    'menu_name' => '',
                    'display' => '1'
                ),
            );
```

I created drag and drop sorting, wchich passes the id's in the correct order, like

```
$ids = array('events','betrothed_details','gallery')
```

For each of the $ids array I would need to change the appropriate `order` value in `$sections` array.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($ids as $id) {

  CHANGE THE ORDER VALUE HERE to $i
  $i++;
}
```

How is this done?

Comment: first u do not need $i = 0; $i++; in foreach it just finishes in array's last variable

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear why I have the $i in there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$sections = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 'betrothed_details',
        'name' => 'About us',
        'order' => '1',
        'menu_name' => '',
        'display' => '1'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 'events',
        'name' => 'Events',
        'display' => '1',
        'order' => '2',
        'menu_name' => ''
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 'gallery',
        'name' => 'Gallery',
        'order' => '3',
        'menu_name' => '',
        'display' => '1'
    ),
);
$ids = array('events', 'betrothed_details', 'gallery');
$sorted_sections = array();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    foreach ($sections as $section) {
        if ($section['id'] == $id) {
            $sorted_sections[] = $section;
            break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($sorted_sections);
```

**[Demo Link](http://codepad.org/uwFdYHVq)**